# How to store MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID in Core Data Entity

Tags: core-data, ios5, xcode4.2, media-player

I'm having problems storing the MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID in my core data:  I'm getting the following error:

Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'NSNumber *__strong' to parameter of type 'unsigned long long';

I have the Attribute in my Core Data model "profileItemsPersistentID" defined as Integer 64.

Thanks in advance

-Pauls.

```
NSNumber *selectedSongID;


- (void) mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *) mediaPicker didPickMediaItems: (MPMediaItemCollection *) mediaItemCollection {

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];

    selectedSong =         [[mediaItemCollection.items objectAtIndex: 0] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
    selectedArtist =       [[mediaItemCollection.items objectAtIndex: 0] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];
    selectedSongDuration = [[mediaItemCollection.items objectAtIndex: 0] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration];

    //Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'NSNumber *__strong' to parameter of type 'unsigned long long'; 
    selectedSongID =       [[mediaItemCollection.items objectAtIndex: 0] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID];

    NSLog(@"selectedSongID: %@",selectedSongID);
}

- (IBAction)barButtonSave:(id)sender 
{

    [profileItemsClass setValue:selectedSong forKey:@"profileItemsSong"];
    [profileItemsClass setValue:selectedArtist forKey:@"profileItemsArtist"];
    [profileItemsClass setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:songLength] forKey:@"profileItemsSongDurationInSeconds"];
    [profileItemsClass setValue:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLongLong:selectedSongID] forKey:@"profileItemsPersistentID"];

    [profileItemsClass setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:numberOfRows + 1] forKey:@"profileItemsSongOrder"];



    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil)
    {
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error])
        {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Paul,

Sometimes the error messages say exactly what is wrong. Your code:

```
selectedSongID = [[mediaItemCollection.items objectAtIndex: 0] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID];
```

While I haven't compiled the below code, it resolves your error:

```
selectedSongID = [[[mediaItemCollection.items objectAtIndex: 0] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID] unsignedLongLongValue];
```

Andrew

Comment: Andrew.  Thanks for the response.  I must have posted this late last night as the above line didn't have the error as indicated.  It was further down.